# Can not find or load main class

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans to create a Java desktop application. Everything is fine inside Netbeans. But when I try to run the `.jar` file created in the `dist` folder of my project's workspace, I get the following error: `can not find or load main class`.

I have recently upgraded to Java 1.7.0_03. Do you think this may be the reason? The new JDK is located inside `glassfish` and I don't understand why?!

By the way when I build the same application in Mac OS X with Java 1.6 installed I don't have any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the jar file by double clicking it, then the error is that the manifest.mf file(usually in META-INF folder) need to have the main-class defined.

have a look at http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html

the part

> Main-Class: com.package.MYMainClass

else if you are running from command prompt, then

```
java -jar my.jar com.package.MYMainClass
```

Comment: thnx.i am not sure how to edit manifest, but i managed to run from command prompt as u said. what should  i do now to make it runnable by double clicking?

Comment: and there is no manifest file in meta-inf folder! the manifest is in the root folder of project

Comment: Its a must to have manifest.mf in META-INF. open your jar file as a zip & check if netbeans is creating the META-INF folder. also to edit, just add Main-Class: com.package.MYMainClass at the end of your manifest.mf file

Answer (score 0):

You can also select the Main-Class in Netbeans.
When you first try to run your application, Netbeans will ask which class should be the Main-Class, but you can also select it manually:

`Right click on your project -> Properties -> Run`

At `Main Class` click on `Browse...` and select the class that contains the main method that should be run when starting the application.

Finally, build your project again and the `Main-Class` attribute in `manifest.mf` should be set correctly. Then your application should start as desired, by double clicking the jar or `java -jar myfile.jar`.